# how can i add custom menu in admin panel?

Tags: admin-menu

I am trying to learn how to make themes for WordPress now I am unable to find how to make a [image]custom menu in admin panel related to theme option

want to show a menu in this admin panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **add_menu_page** and **add_submenu_page** to display menu and sub menu.

For more, refeir https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a few ways.

It's probably best if you familiarise yourself with the WordPress Settings API and then look at the WordPress documentation on Creating Options Pages

WordPress Settings API:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Creating WordPress Options Pages:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Another way of creating theme options pages quickly is to use a plugin such as the Redux Framework:
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/redux-framework/